# Using dynamic class in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails project. 
I have a sidenav that only gets generated on specific controllers. Now I need to offset content on pages where the sidenav is active. 
Therefore I added in the application helper:

```
    def sidebarGenerated
    'class="sidebarActive"' if controller_name == "controller1" || 'controller2' || 'controller3'
end
```

and in the application view:

```
<body <%= sidebarGenerated %> >
  <header <%= sidebarGenerated %> ><%= render 'layouts/header' %></header>
  <main <%= sidebarGenerated %> >
```

and in application.scss:

```
    .sidebarActive {
  header, main, footer {
   padding-left: 240px;
 }
```

However, content doesn't offset on pages using the mentioned controllers. Any idea why? thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a flaw in your logic at:

```
if controller_name == "controller1" || 'controller2' || 'controller3'
```

What you really want is:

```
if controller_name == "controller1" || controller_name == 'controller2' || controller_name == 'controller3'
```

Which can be better expressed by:

```
if %w[ controller1 controller2 controller3 ].include?( controller_name )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css must be wrong.I think what you want is something like this:

```
header.sidebarActive, main.sidebarActive, footer.sidebarActive {
   padding-left: 240px;
}
```

or like this:

```
header, main, footer{
  &.sidebarActive{
    padding-left: 240px;
  }
}
```

PS：@Brad Werth is right, there is some problem in your condition.